# _.sum(_.values(x)) ,if x's values are not all numbers

Tags: javascript, typescript, lodash

I have an object similar to this :

```
obj = { name:"myobject", MON: 3, TUE: 5}
```

I am trying to do a `_.sum(_.values(obj))` and push that value into an array `this.hours.push(_.sum(_.values(obj)))` .

I am expecting an array like this `[8]`(the reason I want to store it inside array is because I might want to parse multiple objects in the future). How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter out the non-numbers.

```
const obj = { name: "myobject", MON: 3, TUE: 5 };
const numbers = _.filter(obj, x => typeof x === 'number');
const total = _.sum(numbers);
```

Comment: i assume you meant const total = _.sum(numbers);

Comment: Ah, yes. Quite.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anyone need it, Adding regular way to do this apart from @mbojko answer:

```
const obj = { name: "myobject", MON: 3, TUE: 5 };
var total = 0;
_.forOwn(obj, function(value) {
  if(typeof value === 'number')
    total += value;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `_.sumBy()` and return 0 for non numeric values:

```js
const obj = { name:"myobject", MON: 3, TUE: 5}

const result = _.sumBy(_.values(obj), v => _.isNumber(v) ? v : 0)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
```